# Error SSL handshake when accessing the Analytics Dashboard profile

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After running wso2server.bat, worker.bat, dashboard.bat, I get an error when trying to access Analytics Dashboard like business-role, monitoring, policies, portal.

```
"Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown"
```

what should I do, so that the dashboard analytics running normally
[image: error_log]

Comment: What URL did you use to access the dashboard?

Comment: Also, what's the CN (and the SAN-SubjectAlternativeNames if exist) values of your public certificate. You can get your public certificate from below command.
`keytool -list -v -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks` Alias and password values can be found in the `carbon.xml` file.

Comment: `https://192.168.43.211:9643/portal` and `https://192.168.43.211:9643/monitoring`

Comment: How did you solved ssl hand shake error?

Answer (score 0):

SSL Handshake error can be caused due to several reasons. Know the [possible causes that can lead to SSL handshake errors](https://integrationhelp.com/know-what-is-ssl-handshake-error/). This reference also has a link with details on SSL handshake semantics that will help you understand the problems better.

In this case that you are faced with, according to these references, it could be that the cipher suite algorithm does not match between your browser and server. You could try different browsers to see if the problem goes away. If not, you will have to check on the server certificate.