# WSO2 IS - Analytics : `Error while SSL handshake` error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to link WSO2 IS and Analytics.

Basically I'm following tutorial from WSO2 page(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/prerequisites-to-publish-statistics/). And also checked some tutorials in blog(e.g., https://medium.com/@niluka/wso2-identity-analytics-17f62176130e)

Both IS server and WSO2 IS Analytics runs well until I try to use portal. Here is my problem.

1. I can login at user-portal and other pages, but the log doesn't shows at portal.
2. When I login at portal, this error occurs from `dashboard.bat`.

```
[2020-09-05 17:52:53,381] ERROR {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SslHandshakeCompletionHandlerForServer} - Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2020-09-05 17:52:53,381] ERROR {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SslHandshakeCompletionHandlerForServer} - Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2020-09-05 17:52:54,514] ERROR {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SslHandshakeCompletionHandlerForServer} - Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2020-09-05 17:52:54,690] ERROR {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SslHandshakeCompletionHandlerForServer} - Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

---

I tried some solutions.

- import the public certificate of WSO2 IS Analytics server to the client-truststore.jks of WSO2 Identity Server, and vice versa. (from this blog: https://medium.com/@niluka/wso2-identity-analytics-17f62176130e)
- and solution from this link: https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/1207

  - I tried this command `keytool -import -alias <alias> -file <file_name> -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon`

    - but the response was :

```
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.10.0\repository\resources\security>keytool -import -alias <alias> -file <file_name> -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon.cer
지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다.
```

(지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다. is 'The specified file could not be found`)

**But the problem remain's same. Dose anyone have other solution or tips for this error? Thanks.**

This is my `deployment.toml` file.

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org"      #refers the base dn on which the user and group search bases will be generated

[database.identity_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2IDENTITY_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.shared_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2SHARED_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[resource.access_control]
context = "(.*)/sample-auth/(.*)"
secure = false
http_method = "all" 

[[event_listener]]
id = "authn_data_publisher_proxy"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityMessageHandler"
name = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.data.publisher.application.authentication.AuthnDataPublisherProxy"
order = 11

[identity_mgt.analytics_login_data_publisher]
enable=true

[identity_mgt.analytics_session_data_publisher] 
enable=true

[event.default_listener.application_authentication]
enable = true
```

Comment: Are you trying this with Chrome? Can you try to access the is-analytics dashboard from a different browser and see whether you still getting this certificate_unknown error? There are similar questions reported. Please have a look at them too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615826/error-ssl-handshake-when-accessing-the-analytics-dashboard-profile-solved and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799846/wso2-is-5-10-cannot-borrow-client-for-ssl-localhost7712-solved

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna Thank you for your comment! Sadly..I've tried both solutions :( "Another browser" and solutions from link you suggested. I'm using windows10 now, is this can be problem?